# How many from the battle were alive after the war in Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, war

The 18 days war of Kurukshetra did played havoc and many lost their lives. Sure there are few who would have survived and lived past it.  Out of those who other prominent personalities lived past that event?

For sure, I know these: Pandavas, Krishna, Ashwathama, Krupar. Who else?

**Edit:**
Any idea about [Jambhavan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jambavan) who lived across yugas right from Trivikrama period to Mahabaratha?

Also, Parasurama seems to appear in Ramayana and in Mahabaratha (who fought with Bhisma on request from Amba/Ambalika). These two were reminded when I stumbled on [this page](http://kiskikahani.openspaceindia.org/articles/the-chiranjeevis-of-the-ramayana-where-are-they-now).

Then is the Sage Vyas who I could see in Mausala Parva at the end.

Comment: After your edit it seems that, you want to know all the important characters survived rather than just the war survivors. That list can be quite long as: Dhritarashtra, Vidura, Vyasa, Balarama, Parashurama, Sanjaya, Adhiratha, Kunti, Gandhari, Draupadi, Dushala, Rukmin-Rukmini ... and even Parikshit. Regarding Jambhavan, there should be a different question, I feel.

Answer (score 6):

Among those who participated in the Kurukshetra war only **ten** were alive after the war. Seven from Pandavas side and three from Kauravas(Dhartarashtras) side.

They are: **Five Pandavas, Vasudeva, Satyaki,  Ashvatthama, Kripa and Kritavarma**

The following words by Dhritarashtra contains the count of the people survived after war from both sides

> 'Alas! **I have heard that the war hath left only ten alive: three of
>   our side, and the Pandavas, seven, in that dreadful conflict eighteen
>   Akshauhinis of Kshatriyas have been slain**! All around me is utter
>   darkness, and a fit of swoon assaileth me: consciousness leaves me, O
>   Suta, and my mind is distracted."
>
> [[Section I, Adi Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01002.htm)

The following words by Ashvatthama contains the names of people survived after the war

> "If, O Duryodhana, thou hast
>   any life in thee still, listen to these words that are so pleasant to
>   hear. **On the side of the Pandavas, only seven are alive, and among the
>   Dhartarashtras, only we three! The seven on their side are the five
>   brothers and Vasudeva and Satyaki; on our side, we three are myself
>   and Kripa and Kritavarma**! All the sons of Draupadi have been slain, as
>   also all the children of Dhrishtadyumna! All the Pancalas too have
>   been slain, as also the remnant of the Matsyas, O Bharata! Behold the
>   vengeance taken for what they had done! The Pandavas are now
>   childless! While buried in sleep, the men and animals in their camp
>   have all been slain! Penetrating into their camp in the night, O king,
>   I have slain Dhrishtadyumna, that wight of sinful deeds, as one kills
>   an animal."
>
> [[Section 9, Sauptika Parva, The Mahabharata]](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m10/m10009.htm)

Answer (score 3):

Listing only those important warriors who participated and survived the war:

### Paandavas

- Krishna
- Yudhishthira, Bheema, Arjuna, Nakula, Sahadeva
- Satyaki
- Yuyutsu

### Kauravas

- Ashwathama (said to be still alive)
- Kripacharya (said to be still alive)
- Kritvarma
- Vrishaketu (Karna's son)

Though there are many sources for this in internet, I would cite this [Wikipedia article on the Mahabharata War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurukshetra_War#Aftermath) for reference.

Comment: You should cite sources.  By the way, this list is not just the important warriors, it's all the warriors.  All the unimportant warriors on both sides died.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, edited. I wrote important warriors, because while reading Mahabarata, at many places I read that many of the troops (battalions) *fled* at various occasions at both the sides. We never know, how many of them returned later to get killed :)

Comment: Just while reading something else, I stumbled on Jaambhavaan. It is sure he crossed Krishnavatar (Jambhavai, Semandhaga mani etc are the results). It is also known that he is very old existing from the Trivikrama time. Was there any mention about Jaambhavaan in the war or after it?

Comment: @Narayanan, I don't have knowledge on [Jaambhavaan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jambavan) except his wikipedia article.

Comment: @iammilind When it says they fled, it just means they left the front lines, not that they quit the battlefield entirely.

Comment: @Narayanan No, Jambavan had no involvement in the Mahabharata war, although he was alive at the time.  See my answer here for details about the activities of Jambavan and other Vanaras during the time of the Mahabharata: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2100/36

Answer (score 0):

The following words by Ashvatthama contains the names of people survived after the war

> "If, O Duryodhana, thou hast
> any life in thee still, listen to these words that are so pleasant to
> hear. **On the side of the Pandavas, only seven are alive, and among the
> Dhartarashtras, only we three! The seven on their side are the five
> brothers and Vasudeva and Satyaki; on our side, we three are myself
> and Kripa and Kritavarma**! All the sons of Draupadi have been slain, as
> also all the children of Dhrishtadyumna! All the Pancalas too have
> been slain, as also the remnant of the Matsyas, O Bharata! Behold the
> vengeance taken for what they had done! The Pandavas are now
> childless! While buried in sleep, the men and animals in their camp
> have all been slain! Penetrating into their camp in the night, O king,
> I have slain Dhrishtadyumna, that wight of sinful deeds, as one kills
> an animal."
>
> [[Section 9, Sauptika Parva, The Mahabharata]](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m10/m10009.htm)

---

Yudhisthira also told Dhritrashtra how many people died and how many escaped the battle.

https://sacred-texts.com/hin/m11/m11025.htm

"Yudhishthira answered, ‘One billion 660 million and 20,000 men have fallen in this battle. **Of the heroes that have escaped, the number is 240,165.’**

240,165 people also escaped from the battle.