# Size of the Battlefield of Kurukshetra

Tags: mahabharata, war, kurukshetra

Are there any descriptions regarding the size of the battlefield of Kurukshetra, where the War of Mahabharata took place.

This size will be in 3 parts:

1. The size of the ground where actual battle took place.
2. The size of the ground where the camps of pandavs and kurus were situated.
3. The distance between the camps and the battlefield.