# Did Samba participate in Mahabharata war against lord Krishna's wishes?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, war

When *Narayani sena* was given to Duryodhana, Was shri krishna's son samba was the head of that army? 
If yes, then in-spite of being a son of lord Krishna, did Samba go against him in Mahabharatha war?
How did he die?

Related: [How many from the battle were alive after the war in Mahabharata?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8396/1049)

Comment: Did Samba participate in the Kurukshetra war?

Comment: There were few false assumptions in your Qn, Such as, *"Samba was head of army", "Why did he fight against his father's side?", "How was he 'killed'?"*. I have replaced them with genuine queries for objectivity. See if the edits suits you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reference found of Samba participating in the great war.
 **Kritavarma was the head** of Narayani sena and not Krishna's son Samba.

> In the left foot, O monarch, was stationed **Kritavarma accompanied by the Narayana troops**, and those invincible warriors, the gopalas. In the right foot, O king, was Gotama's son of prowess incapable of being baffled, surrounded by those mighty bowmen viz., the Trigartas and by the Southerners. In the left hind-foot was stationed Shalya with a large force raised in the country of Madras. In the right (hind-foot), O monarch, was Sushena of true vows, surrounded by a 1,000 cars and 300 elephants. In the tail were the two royal brothers of mighty energy, viz., Citra and Citrasena surrounded by a large force.  [[Karna Parva]](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m08/m08011.htm)

---

In fact after 36 years from the war, **Samba was killed in an internal fight among the Yadava-s** clan which was intoxicated with power and wine. Other sons of Krishna were also killed:

> Knowing that the hour of destruction had come, the mighty-armed Keshava stood there, eyeing everything. Indeed, the slayer of Madhu stood, raising a bolt of iron formed of a blade of grass. **Beholding that Samva was slain**, as also Charudeshna and Pradyumna and Aniruddha, Madhava became filled with rage. [[Mausala Parva]](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m16/m16003.htm)

Comment: You may add also how Samba is dead irrespective of his participation in the war. It completes the answer. It's easy. The slaughter of the Yadavas.