# Does any scripture talk about extinction of Vanaras?

Tags: scripture, puranas, ramayana, itihasa, vanaras

I have never heard of any scriptures talking much about vanaras after Ramayan and except lord hanuman. And they seem to have gone extinct in today's time except for lord hanuman again. Does any scripture talk about them?

Comment: Nothing about their extinction, although [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2094/what-happened-to-the-vanara-sena-after-the-ramayana) question discusses what happened to them in the war's aftermath.

Comment: Which scriptures before Ramayana talk of Vanaras?