# Past life of Satyabhama

Tags: scripture, krishna, satyabhama

We know that Satyabhama is the second important wife of Krishna.

I found only [this](http://vedicgoddess.weebly.com/joy-ma-blog/devi-sathyabama-2nd-of-krishnas-principle-wives-yogi-ananda-saraswathi-httpswwwfacebookcomyogianandasaraswathi), saying about the past life of her and only one paragraph says about her past life.

Where can I read more about the past life of Satyabhama from authentic texts?

Comment: Isn't Sathyabhama Devi an Avatar of Earth Godess and that's why she was able to kill Narakasura??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Previous life of Satyabhama is described in [Kaartika Masa Mahatmya, Vaishanava Khanda of Skanda Mahapurana.](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/skanda-purana/vol-vi/chapter-21/topic-1)

Satyabhama herself asked Sri Krishna about her previous birth. Satyabhama was **Gunavati**, daughter of **Devasharma** a Brahmana who belonged to Aithreya Gotra. He gave (in marriage) his daughter  Gunavati to **Candra**.

When her father and husband went to forest, they were killed by a Rakshasa. Then Gunavati did **Ekadasi vrata and Kaartika Masa vrata** every year and finally she went to vaikunta. Thereafter, when Devas requested, Lord Vishnu (Sri Krishna) married her she when was born as Satyabhama.

> Srikrsna replied:
>
> O beloved, listen with concentration how you observed meritorious
> holy rites in your previous birth. I shall narrate everything to you.
>
> There was an excellent Brahmana named *Devasarma* in Mayapuri towards
> the end of Kirtayuga. He belonged to the Atreya Gotra. He was master
> of Vedas and Vedangas. When he had become pretty old, he begot a
> daughter named *Gunavati*.
>
> He had no son. He gave his daughter (in marriage) to his disciple
> named *Candra*. He considered him his son and the disciple of perfect
> self-control (honoured him) like his own father.
>
> Once those two went to a forest in order to bring Kusa grass,
> sacrificial twigs and fuel. They were killed by a Raksasa as hideous
> in form as the god of Death.
>
> Both of them went to the world of Visnu due to the power of their
> respective merits.
>
> On hearing that both of them had been killed by a Raksasa, Gunavati
> became extremely distressed, having been separated from her husband as
> well as her father. She lamented in a pitiable manner. She quickly
> sold all the furniture, utensils etc. and performed according to her
> capacity their obsequies and other holy rites for (their) happiness in
> the other world. Living like a dead person, she continued to stay in
> the same city.
>
> Two Vratas were perfectly observed by her throughout her life till
> death, viz. the Vrata of Ekadasi and the holy rite of *Karttika*. Thus
> Gunavati performed the Vratas every year. Once that slender-bodied one
> became afflicted with fever. She was in great physical pain. O my
> beloved, with great difficulty she went slowly to Ganga for taking her
> bath. When she entered the water, she became distressed with
> chillness. She shivered.
>
> By that time the lady in distress saw an aerial chariot that had come
> from the sky. She got into that aerial chariot and went to the world
> of Vaikuntha. Thanks to the merit of *Karttikavrata*, she came to my
> presence.
>
> When I came to the earth at the request of the Devas headed by
> Brahma, all those groups (of Devas) also came along with me. O
> beautiful lady, all these Yadavas are my own attendants.
>
> **Your father Devasarma now has the name Satrajit. He who had been called by the name Candra is Akrura now and you are that splendid
> Gunavati.**
>
> You gave me great delight, thanks to the merit of the Kārtikavrata.

You can read rest of the chapter to know story behind Kaartika Masa Mahatmya which corresponds to months of October and November.

Comment: How did , someone goes to Vaikunta would come back on earth again?. I thought they would be permanently liberated?

Comment: @sysinit i think staying with Krishna (Vishnu) is technically same as staying in Vaikunta. She might have again gone to vaikunta after Krishna Avatara like how attendants of Vaikunta were born in Yadava race.

Comment: Isn't Sathyabhama Devi an Avatar of Earth Godess and that's why she was able to kill Narakasura??

Answer (score 9):

The story of Satyabhama’s  past life or former birth is also described in **Padma Purana – Uttar Kanda –Part  VIII – Chapter 88 & 89 – An account of Satyabham’s former birth.**

In the end of the previous chapter Satymabhama asks Shree-Krishna about her past life .

> Satya said:
>   **31-33.** Formerly (i.e. in my previous existence)
>   which gift (did I give), which vow (did I observe), or which penance
>   did I practise, that I, a mortal, have become like Parvati in this
>   mortal (world), and that I always occupy half (the portion) of your
>   body, always ride Garuda, and went with you to the abode of deities
>   like Indra? Therefore, I desire to ask you, what aus- picious (act) I
>   did in the other (i.e. previous) existence, what (kind of) character I
>   had, and whose daughter I was?

And then Shree-Krishna tells her all about her previous existence.Here is the excerpt.

> **34.45** At the end of the Krta age in Mayapuri there was an  excellent brahmana of Atri's family, Devasarman by   name, who had
>   mastered the Vedasand the Vedangas. The old man had a daughter,
>   Gunavati by name. Being sonless, he gave his  daughter to his disciple
>   named Candra(sarman).   He (i.e. Devasarman) looked upon him as his
>   (own) son, and he who had controlled his passions. The two,  desiring
>   to collect  kusas and fuel, once went to a forest.
>
> The two then roamed  in  the forest at the foot  of the Himalaya
>   mountain. Then they saw a  fierce demon coming (to them). With their
>   entire body overcome by fear and unable to run , they were killed by
>   demon with death like form.
>
> ---

Chapter 89

> **1-4.**    Then Gunavati, after hearing that the two were  killed by a 
>   demon,  being overcome   by grief for  her father and husband, she
>   plunged into the ocean of grief and was overcome by it.
>
> She, doing auspicious acts, sold all domestic articles and performed
>   the rites beneficial to the two in the next world.  She, highly
>   devoted to Visnu, calm, truthful, pure and with her senses controlled,
>   lived in that city only and sustained her life.  **From birth till death
>   she properly observed two vows: the vow of Ekadasi and the vow of
>   (i.e. relating to) Kartika.**
>
> **15-30**.   In this way Gunavati, always devoted  to Visnu's followers,
>   and having fixed her mind on him, passed every year.
>
> O dear one, once she who was emaciated due to old age and was
>   tormented by fever, slowly, somehow, went to Ganga to bathe. When, 
>   after she got into the water , she trembled  and was oppressed by cold
>   and frightened, she saw an aeroplane that came from the sky. From the
>   sky it approached with (beings) having Visnu's form, having conches,
>   discs and maces in their hands, and properly marked with banners
>   having (the pictures of) eagles. She got into the aeroplane served by
>   a bevy of celes- tial nymphs. The attendants took her being fanned by
>   chowries, to Vaikuntha.
>
> Your father became (i.e. was born as) this king Satrajit. He who was
>   Candrasarman (became) Akrura, and you are that Gunavati, O auspicious
>   one.
>
> **Since you offered all that vow etc. to Visnu of the from of your
>   husband, therefore, you have become my wife.** Due to that vow only
>   which you formerly (i.e. in the former existence) observed in Kartika,
>   from birth till death, you will never be separated from me.
>
> ---
>
> [image]

Comment: Isn't Sathyabhama Devi an Avatar of Earth Godess and that's why she was able to kill Narakasura??

Answer (score 0):

#### Devī Satyabhāmā was the wife of Ahirāvaṇa in her previous birth (as Chandrasenā), as per Bhāvārtha Rāmāyaṇa.

As I discuss in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/50450/17833) about the story of Ahirāvaṇa & Mahīrāvaṇa, the past life of Devī Satyabhāmā is also referenced.

> #### [Chapter 51](https://archive.org/details/BhavarthRamayanHindi/page/n1007/mode/2up) to [Chapter 54](https://archive.org/details/BhavarthRamayanHindi/page/n1015/mode/2up), Yuddha Kānḍa of Bhāvārtha Rāmāyaṇa.
>
> - **As per 'śrī Bhāvārtha Rāmāyaṇa' of Eknath, which is in Marāṭhī language, Satyabhāmā in her previous life was called Chandrasenā, the
>   wife of the demon king Ahirāvaṇa.**
> - However, when she saw Śrī Rāma in her palace (kidnapped by her husband on a request from Lankā-patī Rāvaṇa), she immediately gets
>   enamored and infatuated with the Lord.
> - On a pre-condition to marry Śrī Rāma, she agreed to divulge her husband's death secrets to Hanumāna.
> - After killing Ahirāvaṇa though, Śrī Rāma refused her advances on account of his vow of 'eka-patnī-vrata'.  But he promises to marry Chandrasenā in his next
>   appearance on Earth as Śrī Kṛṣṇa, and, Chandrasenā thus, shall be born
>   as Satyabhāmā (daughter of king Satrājit).

Comment: Isn't Sathyabhama Devi an Avatar of Earth Godess and that's why she was able to kill Narakasura??

Comment: I find idiots downvoting this answer. I corrected it (my oath to upvote any downvoted answer, assuming that the answerer does with the best of intentions).

Comment: Both narrations could be right.  May be Satya was Chandrasena, and a later incarnation of Gunavathi.  This answer gives some references and hence cannot be dismissed or downvoted.