# Are there any details of past life of Rukmini Devi?

Tags: mahabharata, puranas, krishna, reference-request, rukmini

[Here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15507/29862), there is a question regarding the past life of Satyabhama Devi.

Is there a similar narration of the past life of Rukmini Devi?