# Did Shree Hanuman have a child from Raavana's daughter SuvannaMaccha?

Tags: ramayana, hanuman, ravana, brahmacharya

While reading about (legendary) creature called [Mermaid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mermaid), I stumbled upon 1 of the examples [SuvarnaMaccha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suvannamaccha).

[image]

While building Ramasetu, this daughter of Raavana was an obstacle, but later fell in (mutual) love with Hanuman and had an offspring, [Macchanu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macchanu).

This story predominantly appears in Combodian, Thai and some other versions of Ramayana:

> When several volunteers have stepped forward Hanuman leads them into
>   the waves. They find a large number of mermaids underwater. As they
>   watch, a new rock is tossed in. The mermaids living underwater take
>   the rocks and carry them away. Hanuman looks for their leader. He
>   spots lovely mermaid supervising the others. He swims towards her but
>   she skillfully evades him. Time and again he begins an attack but it
>   comes to nothing.
>
> Hanuman finds he is falling in love with the creature. He changes his
>   tactics and begins to silently woo her. She responds to him and soon
>   they are together at the bottom of the sea.
>
> Later, Hanuman asks the mermaid why she is stealing the rocks. She
>   tells him that she is Suvannamaccha, a daughter of Ravana (the demon
>   who had abducted Sita). When Ravana saw Hanuman's Vanaras building a
>   causeway he instructed Suvannamaccha to stop it.
>
> Hanuman tells the mermaid why he is building the causeway. He tells
>   her of the abduction of Sita, the battle between Rama and her father
>   Ravana, how they started to build a bridge, and in consequence was
>   ordered to finish the causeway within seven days or pay with his life.
>
> Suvannamaccha turned to Hanuman and her eyes were filled with love. No
>   more, she said, would she prevent Hanuman from completing his mission.
>   Her mermaids underwater would, in fact, return all the stolen rocks to
>   the causeway.
>
> They parted as lovers part but it was not to be the end for them.
>   Hanuman had left a seed with Suvannamaccha and soon she would give
>   birth to their son, Macchanu.

Is this really true?
Do other versions of Ramayanas also recognize Hanuman as *Akhanda Brahmachari*?

Comment: I don't think so, but we do have different versions of Ramayana.

Comment: "Valmiki ramayana" is the ultimate source. Nothing more, nothing Less !

Comment: In one version of Ramayan, when Ahiravan and Mahiravan kidnapped Lord Rama and Lakshmana and take them to Patala loka, Lord Hanuman go there to rescue and finds his son Makardhwaj, who was born from his sweat being swallowed by a fish, while he was returning from Lanka. The story given in question looks a bit similar in terms of fish/mermaid (semi-fish) acting as a female counterpart and son's name Makardhwaj and Macchanu, kind of similar ones.

Comment: @Aby, if you find a good reference, then post it as an answer.

Comment: This is funny story but false story.... No truth inside it

Answer (score 3):

As per one version of Ramayana , bengali version kritiiwasi ramayana , hanuman has only one son magardwaja. It is when lord hanuman was returning after burning Lanka, he tried to clean his face with water of sea and the drops were drunk by fish and son of hanuman born.

There are no other son of hanuman. This story is humbalk story. Lord hanuman was brahmachari. He did not fell in love with anybody except lord rama. Lord hanuman was dedicated devotee of lord rama.

Comment: You should cite sources.  Also, the Valmiki Ramayana doesn't mention any sons of Hanuman.

Comment: Do you have link of valmiki Ramayana?

Comment: Here: http://www.valmikiramayan.net

Comment: There is nothing in this site about ahiravana

Comment: Yeah, the story of Ahriravana/Mahiravana is not found in the Valmiki Ramayana at all.

Comment: I am shocked because this story is very famous then from where this story originated?

Comment: Tulsidas Ramayana?

Comment: It's not found in either the Valmiki Ramayana or Tulasidas' Ramcharitmanas.  The only place I know of where it is found is the Krittivasi Ramayana, a Bengali version of the Ramayana.

Comment: Thanks I mentioned it in answer pl check and let me know or feel free to edit

Comment: By the way, it looks like even the Krittivasi Ramayana doesn't mention Makardhwaja, although it does have the story of Ahiravana/Mahiravana.  Apparently the story of Makardhwaja comes from an even later version of the Ramayana from Orissa: http://www.indologica.com/volumes/vol10/vol10_art19_smith.pdf

Comment: Will u pls change it in answer edit it

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan do you have link where story of Ahiravana/Mahiravana is mentioned?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makardhwaja) states that he makes an appearance in Valmiki's Ramayan. Can you please check the veracity of the source given in Wikipedia? I'll edit the article there accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Well, yes, the other Rāmāyaṇas texts, from the Indian languages, namely the Ānanda Rāmāyaṇa, and the Bhāvārtha Rāmāyaṇa recognize the *Akhanda-Brahmachari* nature of Hanumāna.

However, nevertheless they still maintain that he had a son named Makardhvaja, deriving birth from either Hanumāna's phelgm or sweat. Marriage and wife aren't involved, and hence Hanumāna remains a *Brahmachari*  despite having a son.

---

As discussed in this QnA thread - [Did lord Hanuman have a son?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/686/did-lord-hanuman-have-a-son)

As per:

- the Ānanda Rāmāyaṇa, [Sara Kanda, Sarga 11, Verse 89], Hanumāna's phelgm -

Or

- Chapter 52: [Verse 62 to 74]
  Yuddha Kānḍa, Bhāvārtha Rāmāyaṇa, Hanumāna's sweat -

is swallowed by the Makara/Makardhvaja's to-be Mother, which leads to the birth of Hanumāna's son.

---

Yet, Hanumāna is said to be a *Brahmachari*, as he himself notes in the Yuddha Kānḍa of Bhāvārtha Rāmāyaṇa (*by Santa EkanAth in Marathi*).

> #### [Chapter 52](https://archive.org/details/BhavarthRamayanHindi/page/n1013/mode/1up?view=theater), Yuddha Kānḍa, Bhāvārtha Rāmāyaṇa
>
> श्री राम कृपा मी हनुमंत । कौपीन लांधलों उधरस्थ ॥
>  केव्हाहीं
> स्त्रीसंगाची मात । स्वपनाआंतही न देखें ॥ ५६ ॥
>  जन्मादारभ्य पत्नीभोग
> । म्यां देखिलें नाहीं स्त्रीलिंग ॥
>  केंचा पुत्र झालांसी सांग ।
> मातेसी डाग लाविला ॥ ५८ ॥
>
> > **I was born with a Kaupīna (loin-cloth) due to the favour of Śrī Rāma, (and hence by nature being a *Brahmachari*), I cannot dare enjoy
> > a women in my dreams even. And Since I have never been intimate with a
> > women**, how can you (i.e. Makardhvaja) possibly be my son? You're
> > tainting your mother with such allegations.

---

## To conclude:

- So, as far as Suvannamaccha, a daughter of Ravana, is concerned I think, this story is limited to just the Thai or other non-Indian language version of the Rāmāyaṇas.
- However even in the Rāmāyaṇas from the Indian languages, despite having a son named Makardhvaja, god Hanumāna is nevertheless told to be an *Akhanda-Brahmachari*.