# Was Sri Hanuman a married person?

Tags: ramayana, hanuman, marriage, valmiki

There is a prevalent story about the marital status of Sri Hanuman that He was married to Suvarchala, the daughter of the Sun.  However, this story does not find place in Srimad Ramayana, which is an authoritative text on Ramayana.

However, the following slokas from Srimad Ramayana does give an indirect reference to his marital status.

---

The following slokas are from Sundara Kanda.  Sri Hanuman, after scrutiny of all women of Ravana, thinks as follows:

पर दार अवरोधस्य प्रसुप्तस्य निरीक्षणम् || ५-११-३७
इदम् खलु मम अत्यर्थम् धर्म लोपम् करिष्यति |

"My seeing sleeping house of other people's wives will do a great deficit to dharma."

न हि मे पर दाराणाम् दृष्टिर् विषय वर्तिनी ||५-११-३८
अयम् च अत्र मया दृष्टः पर दार परिग्रहः |

"My sight is indeed not in the matter of other wives here. These other's wives have been seen by me."

---

Nowhere in Srimad Ramayana, the marital status of Sri Hanuman was described.

My doubt :   Here Sri Hanuman was saying पर दाराणाम् - other's  wives.  If Sri Hanuman was a celibate, as per prevalent stories, he should have said WOMEN, but he said **other's wives**.

Can we conclude he was in fact a married person?

Comment: Also related posts: [Did lord Hanuman have a son?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/686/1049) and [Did Shree Hanuman have a child from Raavana's daughter SuvannaMaccha?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8402/1049).

Comment: The prevalent story of Sri Hanuma's marriage with Suvarchala does not find place in Srimad Ramayana, which is an authoritative text on Ramayana.  that is why this question

Comment: @srimannarayanakv Not only in the Ramayana, I don't think Hanuman having a wife named Suvarchala is mentioned anywhere in Hindu scripture.  As far as the Sundara Kanda, Hanuman isn't saying "I shouldn't see women other than my wife", he's saying that married women should only be seen while sleeping by their husbands, so he's doing something wrong by seeing all these married women.  He's not saying anything about his own marital status, just that the women are married to other people and thus he shouldn't be seeing them like this.

Comment: Yes!  Sri hanuma was not saying anything about his own marital status.  However, if he was CELIBATE as per prevalent stories, he should have said   "My seeing sleeping house of WOMEN will do a great deficit to dharma."      instead of "My seeing sleeping house of other people's wives will do a great deficit to dharma."

Comment: @srimannarayanakv There's nothing wrong with an unmarried man seeing an unmarried woman.  The problem is that married women should only be seen sleeping by their husbands.

Comment: In Valmiki Ramayanam, [30th Sarga](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/ayodhya/sarga30/ayodhya_30_frame.htm) it is said that Suvarchala is wife of sun `"Oh Seetha, with thighs like the posteriors of an elephant! Earlier, righeousness (like fulfilling the father's command) was practised by good men. Now, I shall follow that righteousness, like Suvarchala(wife of the sun) following the sun."`