# Wife of Lord Hanumāna?

Tags: temple, hanuman, surya, brahmacharya

As per [this QnA](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/413/17833) on this site itself, it gives complete details of Lord Hanumāna getting married and having family.

> No, Hanuman was technically not a bachelor (Brahmachari). His wife was
> *Suvarcalā* (सुवर्चला) who was the daughter of *Surya* (the Sun god)...
>
> .....
>
> Surya grants
> him a boon that he will still be a bachelor even after marriage as a
> Prajapatya Brahmachari and will maintain his celibacy.

On further research, I was able to find an [article](https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/english.newstracklive.com/ampnews/sc93-nu-1068545-1.html?espv=1) about a temple in *Khammam* district of *Telangana*, named - *Sri Suvarchala Sahitha Hanuman Temple*. This temple is build on this very claim of Hanumāna having a wife. Another temple, based on the same premises is the [*Sri Veeranjaneya Swamy Temple*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gandi_Kshetram), also known as *[Gandi Kshetram](http://www.tadbundveeranjaneyaswamy.org/veeranjaneya-swamy-deities.htm)*, situated in the *Kadapa* district of the *Andhra Pradesh*.

So, What might be the scriptural source and validity of this story?

---

My guess is, it's mainly based on either Jainism or Buddhism based and inspired accounts, and is not within the paradigm of our Hinduism pantheon based stories.
But, still it'll be good to clarify this properly in here and see if sources exist within *Hinduism* itself maybe?

Comment: A related post: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16424/who-is-suvarchala-is-she-wife-or-daughter-of-sun-god

Comment: [Tadbund Anjaneya temple](http://www.tadbundveeranjaneyaswamy.org/veeranjaneya-swamy-deities.htm) in Hyderabad also has Sri Suvarchala Veeranjaneya Swamy as Utasave murthi

Comment: @TheDestroyer, Thanks very much. I added this too, to the question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Who is Suvarchala? Is she wife or daughter of Sun God?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16424/who-is-suvarchala-is-she-wife-or-daughter-of-sun-god)

Comment: @Mr.Sigma., No, definitely not. It's very much related though.

Comment: I am not much into all these kind of stuff, however I found [this](https://archive.org/details/SriParasaraSamhitaHanumaCharitramVol1/page/n71/mode/2up) from the same [this](https://archive.org/details/SriParasaraSamhitaHanumaCharitramVol1/page/n19/mode/2up) . [This](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/17899/21353) answer was trying to cite from it but says parashara samhita hanuman charitra is not authentic.

Comment: @Proxy, hmmm. Interesting. Thanks!