# What is the main reason for worshipping Hanuman ji?

Tags: hanuman

We worship Hanuman ji. He is a great great devotee of lord Shri Rama. He is considered as an [avatar of lord Shiva](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16987/8735)

What is the main reason that Hanuman ji is worshipped?

Is it because he is avatar of lord Shiva?

Or

Is it because he is such a great devotee?

Or

If there was any boon granted to him that he will be worshipped?

There are other great devotee avatars like Narada ji but they are not widely worshipped like Hanuman ji. Hence my question.

Comment: Personal believe: Hanumana birth was under divine planning, not only to help Rama but to help all people of all yugas. Means,Hanumana took birth to help every being by staying on Earth. This is the reason that even being a great devotee of Rama, He (Rama) ordered him stay on Earth by being immortal instead of taking him to his divine abode(Vankuntha) like all other devotees. Worship of Hanumana was pre-decided for sake of all people so that people will enjoy fruits of Shri Hanumana's devotion.

Answer (score 1):

The following analysis on Sri Hanuman ***was made based on Ramayana*** by Sage Valmiki.  Folk stories or narrations from Puranas were not taken into account.

---

- Sri Hanuman was described to be the son of Vayu, but not the incarnation of Shiva.
- Sri Hanuman was described as the follower of dakshinAchAra - Vedic way of life.  No one else was described in Ramayana so.
- He had immense strength
- Like Sri Krishna in Mahabharata, he is highly learned, righteous to the core, blessed with supernatural powers, wise, valiant, powerful, fearless but **yet humble in character**.
- His behaviour is like that of a sad guru.
- He is not the devotee of Sri Rama.  By the time Sri Rama met him, he had already attained siddhis/powers and a learned person

---

Sage Valmiki described Sri Hanuman in Kishkinda Kanda.  According to Srimad Ramayana, Sri Hanuma is bestowed with the following further capabilities/boons.

- 1. No Astra can do harm to him.  Even Brahma Astra can keep him motionless for a few moments only
- 2. Lord Indra gave him a boon that Death will touch him at his wish only
- 3. His speed is equal to Garuda himself.
- 4. He had attained SIDDHIS

---

Sage Valmiki described the preparations of Sri Hanuma, when he decided to flew in Southern direction for searching Seeta in Lanka, as follows:.

> अञ्जलिं प्राङ्मुखः कृत्वा पवनायात्मयोओनयो | ततो हि ववृधे गन्तुं
>   दक्षिणो दक्षिणां दिश्म् ||      (Sundara Kanda 1 Sarga  9 sloka)
>
> Hanuma turned towards east, saluted his father, the Lord of Wind and
>   increased his body to go towards southern direction.

Sage Valmiki used the words **दक्षिणो दक्षिणां दिश्म्** in the sloka.  If the words दक्षिणां दिश्म् indicate Southern Direction, why did the sage used the word **दक्षिणो** (**dakshinO**) again?

The word  दक्षिणो (Dakshino) was used to indicate that Sri Hanuma is the follower of DAKSHINAACHARA, i.e., the VEDIC way life.  Sri Hanuma was described by the Sage Valmiki as expert in all Vedas (kishkinda kanda).

During RAMAYANA period we will come across Ravana and Indrajit, the elder son of Ravana.  They used to follow **VAAMACHARA** - non-Vedic way of life.

---

Sri Hanuma shows immense strength and dexterity in SUNDARA KANDA.  He even says that he alone can slay Ravana alongwith his army.

Even Ravana acknowledges Sri Hanuma’s capabilities in Sundara Kanda (Sarga 46 Sloka 11 ).

> दृष्टा हि हरयः शीघ्रा मया विपुल विक्रमाः | वाली च सह सुग्रीवो
>   जाम्बवान् च महाबलः ||  नीलः सेना पतिः चैव ये च अन्ये द्विविद आदयः | न
>   एव तेषाम् गतिः भीमा न तेजो न पराक्रमः ||  न मतिः न बल उत्साहो न रूप
>   परिकल्पनम् |
>
> "Earlier, I saw the Vanara-s of a great prowess like Vali and
>   Sugreeva, the mighty Jambavan, Nila the Chief of army and so on like
>   Dvivida.”
>
> “Their scheme of performance is not so fearful as this; nor their
>   efficacy, nor their prowess, nor their intellect, nor this capacity to
>   change their form or energy at will."

---

He remained  in sidelines till called for.  When he led the way, his brilliance sparkled in every action, be it acting as a messenger, an advisor, fighting as a warrior, etc, he executed.  He did not intervene when others are fighting their battle.

Seeta understood the strength of Sri Hanuman.  However, Seeta did not want Sri Hanuman to take her to her husband.  Her husband has to fight the battle and win her in the battle.

> कामम् अस्य त्वम् एव एकः कार्यस्य परिसाधने | पर्याप्तः पर वीरघ्न यशस्यः
>   ते बल उदयः ||
>
> "O Hanuma, the annihilator of enemies! You are yourself surely
>   sufficient single-handed completion of this task. Your elevated energy
>   is creditable indeed."
>
> शरैस्तुः सम्कुलाम् कृत्वा लन्काम् पर बल अर्दनः | माम् नयेत् यदि
>   काकुत्स्थः तस्य तत् सादृशम् भवेत् ||
>
> "But, it will be appropriate for Rama, who destroys the hostile
>   forces, to take me with him, after routing Lanka with his arrows."
>
> तत् यथा तस्य विक्रान्तम् अनुरूपम् महात्मनः | भवति आहव शूरस्य तत्त्वम्
>   एव उपपादय ||  (Sundara Kanda 56 Sarga 3-5 Slokas)
>
> "Therefore, you act in such a way that the high-souled Rama, valiant
>   in battle, may exhibit prowess worthy of him."

That was why, Sri Hanuman did not try to stop, though being capable, Indrajit when he was attacking, staying invisible by using his ascetic powers,  Sri Rama and Lakshmana.

If ***he intervenes***, their glory diminishes and ego gets hurt. **Sri Rama and Lakshmana had to toil.**  After all it was their battle.  He helped them by remaining in sidelines.

---

His behavior, actions will remind us that of a SADGURU.

A SADGURU will teach you, guide you, ***motivate you in the spiritual path***, but you have to toil all along the spiritual line.  The SADGURU will remain as a spectator of your efforts.

---

That is why we venerate Sri Hanuman.

Comment: Most part of this answer portrays how powerful Hanuman ji is. But so were/are many other figures (Jambavan/Vali). There are stories of their greatness and power too. But they don’t have place equal to lord Hanuman. I am sure they were also following dharma properly. With all due respect I don’t agree that these qualities (power and Vedic lifestyle) alone make Lord Hanuman worthy of worship.

Comment: Sri Hanuman have other qualities, which others didn't have, as well. Please read answer again @Ketan

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question can be given in a single poem(sloka):

> Buddhir Balam Yasho Dhairyam
>
> Nirbhayatvam Arogata
>
> Ajaadyam Vak Patutvam Cha
>
> Hanumat Smaranat Bhavet

By remembering(smarana) Hanuman one is blessed with:

- Intelligence(Buddhi):He was a scholar par excellence.He knew all the nine vyakaranas.(grammatical works in sanskrit)
- Physical strength(Balam): This is the most prominent quality of Hanuman.He had immense strength.
- Fame ( Yasha):He had immense popularity among Vaanaras and all his opponents were fearful of him due to his fame.
- Courage(Dhairyam)/ Fearlessness(Nirbhayatvam): His courage took him to Lanka after his travel across the ocean and his fearlessness startled Ravan himself.
- Good health(Arogata), Absence of dullness(Ajaadyam): He was very fit and agile at the same time. Laziness was never his quality due to his ever ready nature.
- Eloquence in speech(Vaakpatutvam):His speech was eloquent and purposeful. His speech soothed Seeta in captivity .His speech defied Ravana and warned Ravana of the impending consequences of his behaviour towards Rama.
- Lord Hanuman is an epitome of all the above characteristics. He displays all these characteristics in Ramayana. Mankind must try to emulate his characteristics in real life situations to tackle all the problems it faces.

As Sugreeva puts it Ramayana :

> “Desa Kaalaaanugantasya Nayasya Nayapanditaha”
>
> “A scholar is one who behaves/acts according to the place and time that he is in.”

[Source](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-people-worship-Hanuman/answer/Manikantha-Sarath)

Comment: Your answer appears copied from [this Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-people-worship-Hanuman/answer/Manikantha-Sarath) without proper attribution. See [How to reference material written by others](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) and [The copy-paste issue, Hinduism version](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48/the-copy-paste-issue-hinduism-version).