# Lord Hanuman in Shaktism

Tags: shiva, hanuman, durga, shaktism, bhairava

I have seen various pictures of Maa Durga with Lord Hanuman and Lord Bhairava.[image: An example of such representation.]

Infact I have even seen in Devi temples having shrine of Lord Hanuman right with Maa Shakti.
While Lord Bhairava has His significance in Shaktism,I don't know much about Lord Hanuman's significance in Shakti traditions. Is it because of Lord Hanuman(like Lord Bhairava) being avatar of Lord Shiva? Lord Hanuman is usually associated with Bhakti traditions of Lord Rama.

As a Bhakta of both Lord Hanuman and Maa Durga I want to know significance of Lord Hanuman in worship of Maa Durga and other forms of Shakti like Maa Kali and others and the relation between the same.

Edit : I just came across [this article in Siddha pedia about Lord Hanuman](https://kaulapedia.com/en/vajra-hanumant-diksha/)
Which goes deeper into tantric as well as Bhakti aspect of Lord Hanuman.

Also from what I have seen(at least in North India), is that during navaratri small boys are referred as Langura(s) while small girls are called Kanya(s). And in Devi temples the murti of Langura generally resemble that of Lord Hanuman in his child form. An example might be this murti of Sri Bala Vijaya Mast Hanuman from in Shri Mahakaleshwar Jyotirlinga Ujjain. [image: Bala Hanuman in Shree Mahakaleshwar Jyotirlinga Ujjain]
Even there is no use of Langura term here but murtis resemble like that those of Langura in devi temples.

I have asked separate question for this. Linked here : [Who is Langura worshipped in Devi temples?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/53110/who-is-langura-worshipped-in-devi-temples)

Comment: Hanumana being accompanied by Durga is restricted to North India only. Inspite of being Mahadeva's avatara, Hanumana's worship is conducted according to Vaishnava rites (which involve Vaishnava pecularities like urddhvapundra, tulasi & white sandal) & not Shaiva rites (which involve Shaiva peculiarities like tripundra, bilva leaves, rudraksha & bhasma), so His worship isn't much popular among non-Vaishnavas. Even among Vaishnavas, He isn't worshipped much outside the Ramanandi community. Srivaishnavas evoke Hanumana only while adorning Ramachandra & as a gate-keeper alongside Garuda.

Comment: Some Tantrik texts mention the application of Hanumana mantra in cases like curing disease, winning wars, subduing malefic spirits, general welfare, acquiring siddhis etc which are highly generalised. The only unique application of Hanumana mantra that was found is securing release from imprisonment. It is likely that Tulsidas was single-handedly responsible for raising Hanumana's popularity to its current standards. Before Hanumana's advent, Kartaviryarjuna was the widely revered protective deity.

Comment: @AnubrataBit so many misconceptions you have. Lord Hanuman is widely worshipped pan Vaishnavism including Krishna Centric sects even sects like ISKCON worship and adore Hanuman. Coming to Shaiva and Shakra traditions I don't know much but Lord Hanuman is definitely one of the most worshipped deities in Tantra. Probably after Lord Shiva and Maa Shakti. It has nothing to do with North/South traditions either. Hanuman is worshipped in south india especially Karnataka, Telangana and Andhra Pradesh.

Comment: @AnubrataBit what? Why would kartavirya arjun be worshipped as protection when he himself became adharmic and was defeated? It's like worshipping ravana for protection. Lord Hanuman never left the path of Dharma and also is undefeated. Anyways your comment has nothing to do with my question. Seems with your comments you want to show Lord Hanuman worship as a recent north indian sectarian phenomenon. Which is not true even before Tulsidas,Lord Hanuman was popular but yes Tulasidas did help in popularizing Lord Hanuman's worship. Search about Lord Hanuman in Kaula traditions.

Comment: 'Coming to Shaiva & Shakta traditions I don't know much but Lord Hanuman is definitely one of the most worshipped deities in Tantra.' That's a rather self-conflicting statement. Secondly, apart from the usual applications (liking curing diseases & removing ghosts), Kartaviryarjuna was mainly worshipped to recover stolen goods & missing people, as per Uddamareshwara Tantra. If you search at the right place, then you will find that numerous compendiums dealing with Kartaviryarjuna's worship were composed at one time by people like Lakshmana Desikendra & Kamalakara Bhatta.

Comment: @AnubrataBit yes though the first statement sounds contradicting , what I meant was that some who are knowledgeable about tantra told me that Lord Hanuman is one of the most important deities in tantra. One even told me that after Lord Shiva(Lord Bhairava) and Maa Shakti(Maa Kali) ,Lord Hanuman is third most worshipped tantric deity! I was shocked since Lord Hanuman is more marayada sattvik deity. I worship Lord Hanuman in sattvik way.

Comment: @AnubrataBit As for kartavirya arjuna, there might be some tantras for him. I think there are some ravana sadhnas aswell if i am not wrong. But kartavirya was never popular guardian deity. Lord Hanuman is epitome of Bhakti ,jnana and even strength. This was even praised by Sage Valmiki himself. So it's not just a Tulasidasa thing.

Comment: I understand that you are an ardent devotee of Sri Hanumana, but you must accept the truth.

Comment: @AnubrataBit yes I am devotee of Lord Hanuman. And it's true that in your earlier comments you came off as someone who is trying undermine Lord Hanuman's worship. So I apologise if you felt I was rude in my earlier comments. But truth is even in Valmiki Ramayana Lord Hanuman is praised. Read this https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/37814/what-is-the-main-reason-for-worshipping-hanuman-ji Despite being a vanara Lord Hanuman shows all sign of a true Guru. Also read this for tantric significance of Lord Hanuman. https://kaulapedia.com/en/vajra-hanumant-diksha/ (1/2)

Comment: @AnubrataBit  from my above comment we can conclude Lord Hanuman worship is not some recent or even north indian phenomenon. Lord Hanuman is ideal and the greatest Bhakta of all time at the same He is Jnani too and show kindness to devotees even in this age of Kali Yuga. That's why we  see Lord Hanuman carrying flag in images. Actually that flag is representation of Lord Hanuman upholding Dharma in Kali Yuga. Jai Sri Ram (2/2)