# Who is Langura worshipped in Devi temples?

Tags: hanuman, durga, shaktism, bhairava

This is in continuation with my previous question of representation of Lord Hanuman in Shakta traditions with Maa Durga and Lord Bhairava. [image: An example of such representation]

You can find this question here : [Lord Hanuman in Shaktism.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/53045/lord-hanuman-in-shaktism)

Now coming to this question, generally from what I have seen(at least in North India), is that during navaratri small boys are referred as Langura(s) while small girls are called Kanya(s). And in Devi temples the murti of Langura generally resemble that of Lord Hanuman in his child form. An example might be this murti of Sri Bala Vijaya Mast Hanuman from in Shri Mahakaleshwar Jyotirlinga Ujjain.
Here is a picture of same :  [image: Sri Bala Hanuman murti from Sri Mahakaleshwar Jyotirlinga from Ujjain]
Even there is no use of Langura term here  but murtis resemble like that those of Langura in devi temples.